# ASP.NET MVC model binding returns null ONLY on Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, model-binding

I have a ASP.NET MVC web application deployed on an IIS Express. The problem I am facing is that my model binding is returning null **ONLY on Internet Explorer**.

The scenario is that when user **does not** upload a document, `SimpleObject.File.File` is supposed to return `null`, but only on IE, `SimpleObject.File` returns null, which is breaking our website.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

**Model**

(`SupportingFile` is a wrapper class for `HttpPostedFileBase`, `SupportingFile.File`):

```
public class SimpleObject: IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "SupportingFiles_Name", ResourceType = typeof(ValidationStrings))]
    public SupportingFile File { get; set; }

    public SimpleObject()
    {
        this.File = new SupportingFile();
    }
}
```

**Part of the form**

```
<div class="form-row hide">
    @Html.RequiredLabelFor(m => m.File.File,"Upload document",true)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File.File, new {type="file"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.File.File)
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken] //CSRF validation
public ActionResult Index(SimpleObject model)
{
    if (model.File == null) 
    {
        throw new Exception("There is a special place in hell for IE");
    }
}
```

The interesting is that, I am not even binding `SimpleObject.File` - it is initialised in the default constructor. What I am binding is `SimpleObject.File.File`, and all other browsers (FF, Chrome) work as expected except for IE...

Comment: Specific version of IE? Same behavior with Edge?

Comment: Hi @TiesonT. It is happening also on Edge, basically Edge, IE 11,10,9 and maybe lower versions...

Comment: IE tends to not like hidden file inputs. If you remove the hide class, does it post correctly?

Comment: Hi @TiesonT. The hide attribute gets removed by JS once the user chooses to upload a document

Comment: @JoelMin were you able to find the issue? I am having the same issue. just returning a checkbox model value, on ie 11 it is returning null but it is fine on edge and chrome and firefox

Answer (score 0):

i know this is old, but i had a problem like this today and the reason for not working on IE was because my input field was disabled, i changed it to readonly, worked with no problems